# GET Request filtered by date REST API

Tags: java, mysql, rest, date

Im trying this code to return me a list of posts between two dates (from-to) but it returns instead 404 error. here's my code:

```
@GET
@Path("searchPostsBetween/{idUsr}/{from}/{to}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Post> searchPostsBetween(@PathParam("idUsr") Integer idUsr, @PathParam("from") Date from, @PathParam("to") Date to) {
    List<Post> postList = super.findAll();
    List<Post> postListAuthor = new ArrayList<Post>();               
    for(int i=0; i<postList.size();i++){
        if(Objects.equals(postList.get(i).getIdAuthor().getIdUser(), idUsr)){
            if(postList.get(i).getDate().compareTo(from)>=0 && postList.get(i).getDate().compareTo(to)<=0){
                postListAuthor.add(postList.get(i));
           }
        }
    }
    return postListAuthor;
}
```

And here's my request:

```
http://localhost:8080/MySocial/webresources/post/searchPostsBetween/14/2010-09-09/2012-09-09
```

the expected output is a 200 response with a non empty list of post posted by user with ID 14 (there are posts posted by this user between those dates in my database)

Dates are stored YYYY-MM-DD in my Database(Using MySQL 6.3 CE)

Comment: @PathParam("form") should be @PathParam("from") ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misstype. Although the error persists. (Still returning 404) Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: Try to debug and see if the array that you are trying to return is not null at least

Comment: 404 is the "not found" error code, implying that there's some higher level configuration problem because it's not even _finding_ the resource you're getting. Are your other endpoints working? If you strip out all your code in `searchPostsBetween` does it respond? If it doesn't respond, keep removing code until it does.